# Class methods invoked before returning response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class like:

```
@Slf4j
@Data
public class MultipleConfigResponseDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<ConfigResponseDTO> configResponseDTOList;

    public List<Long> getAutoOrder() {
        List<Long> idList = new ArrayList<>();
        ....
        processing
    }
```

Now the above class object is returned as a response of an API. But before returning the response the method in the class is invoked 3 times. I am using spring boot for my web application.

```
@RequestMapping("/queryGoodsConfig/all")
ResponseData<MultipleConfigResponseDTO> queryGoodsConfig(){

List<ConfigResponseDTO> configResponseDTOList = configComponentService.queryAllConfig();

MultipleConfigResponseDTO multipleConfigResponseDTO = new MultipleConfigResponseDTO();
multipleConfigResponseDTO.setConfigResponseDTOList(configResponseDTOList);
return new ResponseData<>(CommonMessageCode.SUCCESS, multipleChannelGoodsConfigResponseDTO);

}
```

Edit: Added Controller code too.

Comment: why @Data annotation? Is it your POJO Entity?

Comment: yes, its a POJO entity. We are using Lombok plugin to create getters setters, hence using @data. Also, the class method is called by Jackson before writing response.

Comment: share the log with required code? please do not share just piece of code.

Comment: Added the controller code .. there are no extra logs generated.

Comment: dude, should learn how to ask question first https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: sure, thanks for the link.